# Set-ADUser: Set Active Directory Users Attribute Data via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to AD - Automation via Powershell and although I managed to do Bulk Modify/Update the Location of our AD users based in our OU for some reason I am having difficulty replicating the script for the OU based in our on site office.

I hope i'm making sense here but probably this will help you answer or help me. Here is my script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "c:\scripts\van.csv"

Get-ADUser -Filter 'DisplayName -like "*"' | Set-ADUser -Replace @{PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName="Van Nuys"}
```

When I ran this script on Powershell what happens is it changes the location of the user's based in our OU not based on Van Nuys. The csv file that I have has DisplayName, Title and Office with the corresponding information of each users.  But I don't know why it's changing the users in our OU.

I hope you can help me.

Sincerely, 
LP

Comment: You're not using your `$users` variable anywhere... You're grabbing every user in your AD and setting their office location.

Comment: What should be my script for me to update the attributes for the users that are only listed on the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your CSV has the sAMAccountName, and you want all users updated to Van Nuys, something like this will work.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "c:\scripts\van.csv"

foreach($user in $users)
{
 Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -Replace @{PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName="Van Nuys"}
}
```

If you really only have their display name, you can TRY modifying it to this, but since it's not a unique identifier you'll be really lucky if it works.

```
foreach($user in $users)
{
 Get-aduser -filter {DisplayName -like $user.Displayname} |Set-ADUser -Replace @{PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName="Van Nuys"}
}
```

Comment: I will try this one. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Will it work if I only have the DisplayName? I only have their Names.

Comment: See my edit. You can try using display name but since it's not unique, there's a really high chance it will fail on quite a few users.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. I will try that. But i think I need a script that will allow me to get bulk samaccount name for a specific Ou.  :)

Comment: Get-aduser is the command then specify the ou and specify -property samaccountname

Comment: I was able to run the script without any errors but when I manually checked on AD it didn't replace the location attribute. What am I missing?